# FAB подпрыгивает над Snackbar'ом

Tags: android

Я пытаюсь сделать плавно поднимающуюся кнопку над снекбаром. Xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="48dp"
    app:fabCustomSize="80dp"
    app:maxImageSize="40dp" />
```

Вызов:

```
        fab.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Message",1500);
        snackbar.show();
    });
```

При использовании

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

fab иногда (каждый 2-й или 3-й раз) на мгновение появляется в верхней точке, затем исчезает и поднимается как и должен. При использовании

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

все работеат плавно. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как я уже сталкивался с багом в версии `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` связанным с размером текста, рискну предположить, что проблема может быть так же связана с этой зависимостью. Попробуйте либо понизить версию до `1.1.0-rc01` либо повысить до `1.2.0-rc01`

Comment: Спасибо, вы почти угадали. Проблема была в зависимости `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0`. На версии 1.0.0 все работает плавно.